# Cannot upload All-in-One WP Migration file to Wordpress hangs at 28%

Tags: plugins

I have a Wordpress website running on AWS (micro instance). I've downloaded All-in-One WP Migration and made a backup of this site.

1. First I tried to upload the .wpress file again to my website. But my file size (545 mb) exceeds the maximum allowed 2 MB.
2. Then I downloadeded the `Increase Maximum Upload File Size plugin` because I was too lazy to edit `.htaccess` or `wp-config.php` and I increase it to 1 GB.
3. Although a warning is given that the hosting provider has set the maximum upload limit (in the Increase Maximum Upload File Size plugin), I can now upload my file, and before I couldn't. But the process hangs at 28.78% as seen in the image:

[image]

4. When I do the same on my localhost using MAMP I get the same hosting provider warning but here it does work fine.
5. The site is run on AWS and I tried to manually modify .htaccess but this file is missing. I manually add it with this content:

`
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 1000M
php_value post_max_size 1000M
php_value memory_limit 800M
php_value max_execution_time 900
php_value max_input_time 800`
```

Then I type in:

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

This doesn't work either.

6. So I add below code to my wp-config.php:

   @ini_set('upload_max_size', '1000M');
   @ini_set('post_max_size', '1000M');
   @ini_set('memory_limit', '800M');
   @ini_set('max_execution_time', '900');
   @ini_set('max_input_time', '800');

Then again:

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

This also doesn't work.

Comment: It might be simplest to SSH into your AWS instance and download the plugin directly there, or use SCP to copy it on, rather than trying to upload it through the admin UI. You then just need to unzip it into your wp-content/plugins folder.